# Adding extra functionality to parent class method without changing its name

Tags: python, class

I have two classes one parent and other child.

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #does something

    def method_parent(self):
        print "Parent"

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def method_parent(self):
        print "Child"
```

After inheriting the parent I want to modify Parent method `method_parent` keeping the original functionality of that method and adding some extra lines of code to that method.

I know that I can create a new method like

```
def method_child(self):
    self.method_parent()
    #Add extra lines of code to perform something
```

But I want to use the original name of method. I can't copy the source for that method because, the method is from a `C` module

what I want to achieve is something like this

```
def method_parent():
    #do parent_method stuff
    #do extra stuff
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can always call code from the parent using **the `super()` function**. It gives a reference to the parent. So, to call `parent_method()`, you should use `super().parent_method()`.

Here's a code snippet (for python3) that shows how to use it.

```
class ParentClass: 
    def f(self): 
        print("Hi!"); 

class ChildClass(ParentClass): 
    def f(self):
        super().f(); 
        print("Hello!");
```

In python2, you need to call super with extra arguments: `super(ChildClass, self)`. So, the snippet would become:

```
class ParentClass: 
    def f(self): 
        print("Hi!"); 

class ChildClass(ParentClass): 
    def f(self):
        super(ChildClass, self).f(); 
        print("Hello!");
```

If you call `f()` on an instance of ChildClass, it will show: "Hi! Hello!".

If you already coded in java, it's basically te same behaviour. 
You can call super wherever you want. In a method, in the init function, ...

There are also other ways to do that **but it's less clean**. For instance, you can do:

```
ParentClass.f(self)
```

To call the f function of parent class.

Answer (score 4):

This is what the `super` function does.

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def method_parent(self):
        super(Child, self).method_parent()
        print "Child"
```

In Python 3, you can call `super` without the arguments, like `super().method_parent()`

Answer (score 1):

You can call the parent method exactly the same way you used for the `__init__` one:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def method_parent(self):
        Parent.method_parent(self)  # call method on Parent
        print "Child"
```

This one is when you want to explicitely name the parent class. If you prefere, you can ask python to give you next class in Method Resolution Order by using `super`:

```
    def method_parent(self):
        super(Child, self).method_parent()  # call method on Parent
        print "Child"
```