# How to not overwrite a method from parent class because of a simple change in the code (in Python)

Tags: python, oop

I have something like this:

```py
def Class1:
    ...
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...a lot of code
        a = query["label_1"].iat[index]
        ...some more operations
        return a

def Class2(Class1):
    ...
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...a lot of code which is the same as Class1
        a = query["label_2"].iat[index]
        ...some more operations which are identical in Class1
        return a
```

As you can see, both "`__getitem__`" functions are basically the same, but only changes "label_**1**" to "label_**2**". There is a way to not to overwrite the entire method in Class2 just because of a little change?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37679421/4996248) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a class variable called `label`:

```
class Class1:

  label = "label_1"

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    a = query[self.label].iat[index]
    return a

class Class2(Class1):

    label = "label_2"
```

And you do not have to overwrite `__getitem__` in `Class2`, just having defined the class variable in `Class2` will work.

Comment: These are class variables, not instance variables.